# Stanford coreference possessive pronoun

Tags: stanford-nlp

Does Stanford's coreference resolution module support resolution for possessive pronouns? For example, consider the following sentences.

"Sandra has 5 candies. Sandra gave all of her candies to Susan."

Would the coreference module be able to determine that "her" refers to "Sandra"? If so, what are the API calls to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, yes it does. It fails for that particular example. It would need some debugging as to why, but it seems to do with the more complex “all of …” noun phrase. If you instead try:

Sandra has 5 candies. Sandra gave her candies to Susan.

in the demo at:

http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process

you can see it working.

There’s nothing special about getting these mentions out in coref chains if they are recognized.  It’s just like regular use of Coref — See, for instance, [StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/demo/StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java).